# UIManagedDocument CompletionHandler & NSNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications, nsdocument

I am using Core Data and was wondering if I am doing things correctly. I am opening my `UIManagedDocument` from a singleton object using the completion handler and *block* below.

```
[[self managedDocument] openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if(success) {
                NSLog(@"DOCUMENT: Success, Opened ...");
                // TODO: Things to do when open.
                // ...
                // ...
            }
}];
```

On my `UIViewController` I have setup an observer to watch for a `UIDocumentStateChangedNotification` to indicate that I can start working with the document.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(documentIsReady) name:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification object:nil];
}
```

This seams to work just fine, but I am conscious that I am not using the callback *block*. One solution might be to create my own notification and post that from the *block*, it does the same thing essentially but just makes the code more obvious to read. Any comments would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that if you only need to notify one controller, once, and only when the document is opened (you have an app that uses a single UIManagedDocument that gets passed between controllers, like the CS193P demo), it would be better to leave only the code inside the completion block.

However, if your app is going to open and close the document many times, and multiple controllers have to be aware of that change, you should use notifications.

Comment: I do have multiple controllers all using NSFetchedResultsControllers and UITableViews, however they do all access he same UIManagedDocument. My problem was that I am setting different NSFetchResultsControllers up on each controller so I need to communicate then the document is ready so that I can do my initial fetch, particularly on the "initial controller" as that gets fired before the managed document is actually ready to use.

Comment: My app is similar. I have about 6 different UITableViews, each one setting its own NSFetchedResultsController. The first controller creates and opens the UIManagedDocument, and keeps it in one of its properties. Every controller from then on is given a copy of a NSManagedObject (the one they will need to create the predicate) and they use it the setup their own NSFetchedResultsController. Since the other controllers cannot be accessed unless the document is open and the tableview in the first controller loaded its data, I don't have to worry about notifying them.

Comment: Mine is pretty much the same, the only difference is the UIManagedDocument is created in a singleton that is instantiated from the AppDelegate. I could have gone with just putting it the AppDelegate, but I have some other bits in there that I wanted to keep separate. Thank you for your help, very much appreciated.